# How to copy a file if modified and avoid rebuilding executables and libraries when running make all?

Tags: cmake

I want to copy a file from the source directory to the binary directory when running `make` or `make all` if the file has been modified. So if only this file has been modified, then no libraries or executables should be rebuilt when running `make`. Only the file should be copied. I tried several approaches, for example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(copy-file VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "testing copy file if modified on make all")
set(FILE_PATH "some_dir/file.txt")
add_executable(hello hello.c)
#add_custom_command(
#    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_PATH}
#    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_PATH}
#    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH})
add_custom_command(
    TARGET hello
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_PATH})
#configure_file(${FILE_PATH} ${FILE_PATH} COPYONLY)
```

Unfortunately, this only copies `file.txt` (when running `make`) if `hello.c` has been modified. If `hello.c` has not been modified, but `file.txt` has been modified, nothing happens when I run `make` (whereas I expected the file to be copied from the source directory to the binary directory)

[Here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/cmake-copy-file-example/tree/not_working) is a link to the source files I used for this minimal example.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Does `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ...` see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) fit your needs?

Comment: @vre Thanks! that seems to work combined with adding a custom target. See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `POST_BUILD` on a custom target. Specify input and output and let CMake take care of the dependency.

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_PATH}
    DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH}
    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_PATH}
)
add_custom_target(copy DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_PATH})
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, what could be the problem with `POST_BUILD` ? In my answer below, I used `PRE_BUILD`. Is that ok to do?

Comment: It is ok. There is no problem. It is just executed unconditionally, there is no change checking. `OUTPUT` and `DEPENDS` are there so that CMake can check timestamps on files, and if `DEPENDS` is newer than `OUTPUT` or `OUTPUT` does not exists, the command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of @vre and adding `copy_if_different` instead of `copy` and then adding `add_custom_target()` that can be used with the custom command like this seems to work now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(copy-file VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "testing copy file if modified on make all")
set(FILE_PATH "some_dir/file.txt")
add_executable(hello hello.c)
add_custom_target(copy ALL )
add_custom_command(
    TARGET copy
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILE_PATH})
```